# spring security and using CustumUserDetails

Tags: spring, security

Can anybody help me with spring security?
I have two folder under views 1: allusers 2: superusers
all users have hasRole("ROLE_USER") and superusers have: haseRole("ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER")
I want when a user how has the ROLE_ADMIN after log in be redirect to the right folder i.e supersusers's folder and that one with only ROLE_USER to the allusers's folder. 
Don't know how can I do it.

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org  /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <!-- interceptor pages -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/allusers/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/superusers/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/getAllUsers"  access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />


    <form-login login-page="/index" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />

</http>
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="
                            select username,password,'true' AS isEnabled from USER where USERNAME=?"  
            authorities-by-username-query="
            select u.username ,r.`ROLE_NAME`,u.`PASSWORD` from USER u, USER_ROLE ur,ROLE r where (u.user_id = ur.user_id) 
            and (r.role_id=ur.role_id)  and u.username =? " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Here is my mvc-dispatcher.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.secure.weblayer" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
     <!--   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/allusers/" />-->
     <!--   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/superusers" />-->
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="mymessages"></property>
</bean>
<bean
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
<bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
   </beans>
```

As you can see I use sql-query in my spring-security.xml for log in. 
I can log in but can not be redirect to any desired pages. But when I in the xml file changethe property to : property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/allusers"
or  : property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/superusers" 
I can get access to all pages in those folders but not at the same time.

Please any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont wanna touch the InternalResourceViewResolver, as that affects all views.

You dont have your access rights correct, should be like this.

all users is normal users and admin users:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/allusers/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />
```

superusers is just admin users

```
<intercept-url pattern="/superusers/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

Also, remove:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
```

And then you just want to redirect to right page after login.
So use this for your login controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper request) {
        if(request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            return "redirect:/superusers";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/allusers";
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi
It doesn't help, still get a http 404.
Can't get access to those jsp-pages under superusers or allusers.

Comment: whats the path to the superusers jsp file?

Comment: Hi 

http://localhost:8080/guard_weblayer/superusers/test
If I understood you correct

Comment: Now I have to have write:
@RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper request) {
        if(request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            return "/superusers/test";
        } else  {
            return "/superusers/hello";
        }
    } 

and not redirect:/superusers/test.

Comment: but why I can't redirect other pages if I have ROLE_User. for example i can't use: else {retrun:/allusers/hello;}.

Do I need to do the same check for every pages I want to get access to.
I mean do I need the same if else check in every controller or how can I use the log in information thought the session?

Comment: the redirect should work.  whats the controller that handles the /allusers/hello path?  Also, have made edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot It's not working properly and I have to examine it more
Thanks.